# Algorithm comparison in unsorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

If I have a unsorted array A[1.....n]

1. using linear search to search number x
2. using bubble sorting to sort the array A in ascending order, then use binary search to search number x in sorted array

Which way will be more efficient — 1 or 2?

How to justify it?

Comment: What is the complexity of a linear search?  What is the complexity of a bubble sort?  What is the complexity of a binary search?  How many searches are you going to do?  Why not use a faster sort?  How would that alter the answer?  How big is N?  Big-O notation is for the asymptotic behaviour as N ⟶ ∞; if N is small, the balance may change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to search for a single number, nothing can beat a linear search: sorting cannot proceed faster than O(n), and even that is achievable only in special cases. Moreover, bubble sort is extremely inefficient, taking O(n<sup>2</sup>) time. Binary search is faster than that, so the overall timing is going to be dominated by O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Hence you are comparing O(n) to O(n<sup>2</sup>); obviously, O(n) wins.

The picture would be different if you needed to search for `k` different numbers, where k is larger than n<sup>2</sup>. The outcome of this comparison may very well be negative.

Comment: Is radix sorting is more efficient to sort the array?

Comment: @Amanda_Q: Any sort which has `O(nlogn)` complexity is efficient. Just pick one. If you are not sure pick `quicksort`

Comment: @Amanda_Q radix sort is the kind that gives yo O(n) performance.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It is not quite true. IF array contains integers (without modifications radix sort doesn't work with floats) and IF they are of no more then M digits, radix sort works in O(n*M).

Comment: @Abstraction Yes, of course - all the limitations of radix sort usability remain applicable, and `M` is assumed to be constant.